# How to make an element stick out from the other side?

Tags: html, css

The basic code:

```
<div parent>
 <div wrapper>
  <div child></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

The basic scheme:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UkhB.jpg

The scheme shows how I want the child element to be positioned. By default, it "walls" to the left of the parent element, but I want it to wall to the right of the parent element. **So let's say if the child element increases in size, it will stick out from the left side of the wrapper instead of the right side of the wrapper.**

**The child is to remain position: static.**

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS for this. Give your parent div a class of parent and child div a class of child. Then in your css use the following code.

```
.parent{
      position: relative;
      }
 .child{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 20%; 
    }
```

Note this top: 20% is subject to change.

Comment: I am sorry for my incompetence, I just updated my question: the child is to remain position: static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position and right properties. On parent use position: relative to set the relative container of children. Use right: 0px on child container to allow going to left side.

Here is a fiddle example: 
[Fiddle example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ec3yydox/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve the result with the desired efficiency by giving position: static to the child element.

For best results you will have to use position: relative and absolute combo as I stated above. Otherwise it will always be a hit and trial of margins that you will have to do manually.